# SyntaxError when trying to create a web todo app

Tags: python, function, lambda, import, syntax-error

I am trying to build a todo app in web version, I named the file as webbb.py and text file as todos.txt

I am trying to build a todo app in web version, When i typed the code below:

```
import functions

todos = functions.get_todos()

st.title("My TO-DO App")

for todo in todos:
    st.checkbox(todo)
```

saved the code in webbb.py file and taking the input from todos.txt file. This code produced the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python_Projects\webbb.py", line 2, in <module>
    import functions
  File "D:\Python_Projects\venv\lib\site-packages\functions.py", line 68
    nodes = tuple(map(lambda (k, v): process_node(inner, k, v),
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I expect it to run in the web browser with the input already given in the todos.txt. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try to remove the parentheses?

Comment: I didn't remove anything from the functions.py file. But I am still getting this error